# When would I not pass a dependency list in React useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

in what case I shouldn't put the empty array [] as dependcies in react useEffect? like

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (true) {
      doStuff()
    }
    return () => null;
  });
```

Is above code even valid?

Comment: It's valid. It means the effect runs every time the component re-renders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is valid.

`undefined` is passed as dependencies and it means `useEffect` runs on every render. So if you want to do some work that shouldn't be run on every render (like adding event listener), you should give a dependency array.

Comment: in what case we put it as undefined?

Comment: if you don't give anything (even empty array) as dependency, `undefined` will be passed.

Comment: yeah you already said that, in what case you that?

Comment: You can pass nothing If you want to do something every single time the component is updated. But more often than not, you likely only want this effect to happen because of something else. Perhaps you want to do something only when data changes, or maybe when the user first sees the component.

Answer (score 4):

just remember 3 rules:

```
useEffect(()=>{},[]) //this is like componentDidMount
useEffect(()=>{}) //this will run every render
useEffect(()=>{},[dep1, dep2]) //this will run if one on de dependency change
```